# Spring @Async method called from within the class

Tags: spring, aop, spring-aop, spring-async

I've an spring component which has some methods as `@Async`.

I want to create a private method and run `@Async` but it won't works because spring doesn't help self invocation from withing the bean...

Is there a simple way to allow a specific private method to allos AOP @Async? or is just simpler to get a threadpool and execute manually?

Answer (score 2):

instead of calling your async method on `this`, inject the bean and call the method on the bean. here is a example:

```
public class MyService {
    
    @Lazy
    @Autowired
    private MyService myService;
    
    public void doStuff() throws Exception {
        myService.doStuffAsync();
        System.out.println("doing stuff sync.");
    }
    
    @Async
    public void doStuffAsync() throws Exception {
        TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(3);
        System.out.println("doing stuff async.");
    }
}
```

- you have to use `@Lazy`!
- you have to call `myService.doStuffAsync()` instead of `this.doStuffAsync()`

Comment: it will work i assume but this looks so ugly

Comment: i agree, but you need to provide more information about your problem.

Comment: Do note that this answer does not cover the main requirement of the question - `allow a specific private method`. Spring AOP cannot advise private methods .

Comment: as i understand OP wants to call a async public method from a private method, which will work fine.

Comment: Rafael, if you find it so ugly, switch to native AspectJ. No more proxies, easy to intercept self-invocation. You cannot have the full power of AspectJ in Spring's own "AOP lite" framework and have to make a choice. But AspectJ also works fine in Spring, just in a somewhat different way with regard to configuration and handling.